# How to retrieve XML using webClient in Spring?

Tags: spring, spring-webclient

I've been trying to retrieve XML using webClient in Spring, but is has not worked out.
I've been getting this error message.

```
UnsupportedMediaTypeException: Content type 'application/xml;charset=UTF-8' not supported for bodyType
```

I think the request was ok, but I failed to get the response as an object. I got '200 ok' from the server.
And I tried to send a request with 'Talend API Tester' to see if I made a right one, I got perfect response.

And I had added '@XmlRootElement', '@XmlAttribute's to my DTO. 
But, I only had gotten an empty List '[]'.

What should I do to solve this problem?

Here are my codes.

```
//Service
public List<SearchResponseDto> search(SearchRequestDto searchRequestDto) {

        System.out.println(requestUrl);

        var uri = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString(requestUrl)
                .queryParams(searchRequestDto.toMultiValueMap())
                .build()
                .encode()
                .toUri();

        return WebClient.create()
                .get()
                .uri(uri)
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
                .headers(head -> {
                    head.set("X-Naver-Client-Id", naverId);
                    head.set("X-Naver-Client-Secret", naverSecret);
                })
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToFlux(SearchResponseDto.class)
                .toStream()
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

//responseDTO
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class SearchResponseDto {

    private String lastBuildDate;
    private int total;
    private int start;
    private int display;
    private List<SearchItem> item;

    @Data
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @AllArgsConstructor
    public static class SearchItem {

        private String title;
        private String link;
        private String image;
        private String author;
        private int price;
        private int discount;
        private String publisher;
        private String isbn;
        private String description;
        private String pubdate;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to configure additional codec to deserialize Xml response

```
WebClient.builder()
        .exchangeStrategies(
                ExchangeStrategies.builder()
                        .codecs(configurer -> 
                                configurer.defaultCodecs().jaxb2Decoder(new Jaxb2XmlDecoder())
                        )
                        .build()
        )
        .build();
```